# How to get only date from ISO8601 timestamp to as string ios?

Tags: objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios9.1

Hi i have date format in ISO8601 as example:

```
NSString *currentDateString = @"2016-01-12T21:21:22.737+05:30";
```

i want to get only date which is **2016-01-12** from this string:

i tried

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateString];
NSLog(@"CurrentDate:%@", currentDate);
```

its retuning null but i want to get date in format of **yyyy-MM-dd**.

Comment: The format string on a date formatter needs to match the string you're converting. Since your string has a lot more than `yyyy-MM-dd`, the date formatter can't parse it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution using **NSRange**:

```
NSString *currentDateString = @"2016-01-12T21:21:22.737+05:30";
NSRange range = [currentDateString rangeOfString:@"T"];
NSString *newString = [currentDateString substringToIndex:range.location];
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Comment: This one not a correct approach, since it is doing a kind of string operation

Comment: If you know any best way of doing is also accepted.

Comment: Serious problem with this solution (assuming your pass `newString` to the date formatter in your question). By truncating the string you are losing the timezone specified in the original string. This means the date formatter will treat the string as local time instead of the in the timezone specified in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-04-18T08:49:58.157+0000";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
// Always use this locale when parsing fixed format date strings
NSLocale *posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:posix];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date = %@", date);
```

Comment: Your solution still prints date = 2013-04-18 08:49:58 +0000.This is not solution i was looking for.

Comment: This solution have converted the string to NSDate format, after that you can changeto any format

Comment: Yes,after you convert to NSDate,you can use like this convert to your desired String  `NSDateFormatter *shotDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [shotDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];NSString *shotDateString = [shotDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];`

Comment: Tom your answer returns shotDateString (null).